# Database for storing nested s3 objects from broom, sweep, or tidy in R

Tags: r, databases

I'm working on a product that requires automated forecasting of time-series data in R & Shiny. Using R's sweep, broom, & tidy packages, I get these 'tibbles', which are like dataframes with nested objects. See below.

[image: R sweep tidyverse dataset]

In order to scale the product, I have to figure out where to store my data - currently keeping them in local .RData files. Need to separate the data storage from the application.

Is there a way to reliably store this data in it's native format, or do I have to parse each of these nested objects to separate tables for a traditional database?

Comment: You could use saveRDS to store it in .Rds native file format.